# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm getting this error "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.".
I've looked at a lot of threads even at stackoverflow and tried those solutions but they dont work for me...like increasing timeouts and buffersizes..

Here's my code on the server..

```
 protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {

        BasicHttpBinding basichttpbinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);

        basichttpbinding.CloseTimeout=TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        basichttpbinding.OpenTimeout=TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        basichttpbinding.ReceiveTimeout=TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        basichttpbinding.SendTimeout=TimeSpan.MaxValue;
       // basichttpbinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;

        ServiceEndpoint servicepoint=new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(serviceType));
         servicepoint.Binding=basichttpbinding;

        ServiceHost servicehost = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

        ((ServiceDebugBehavior)servicehost.Description.Behaviors[typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior)]).IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true;

        servicehost.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        servicehost.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        servicepoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        servicepoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        basichttpbinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 999999999;
       // basichttpbinding.MaxConnections = 999999999;
        //basichttpbinding.MaxConnections = 999999999;
        basichttpbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 999999999;
        XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        quotas.MaxArrayLength = 999999999;
        quotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 999999999;
        quotas.MaxDepth = 999999999;
        quotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 999999999;
        quotas.MaxStringContentLength = 999999999;
        basichttpbinding.ReaderQuotas = quotas;

        //foreach (Uri uri in baseAddresses)
        //{

        servicehost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), basichttpbinding, "");

       // }

        return servicehost;
    }
```

And here's the code I'm using on the client..

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BasicHttpBinding basichttpbinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint=new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IService)));
            endpoint.Binding=basichttpbinding;


            basichttpbinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            basichttpbinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            basichttpbinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            basichttpbinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            basichttpbinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;



            endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            basichttpbinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 999999999;
           // basichttpbinding.MaxConnections = 999999999;
            //basichttpbinding.MaxConnections = 999999999;
            basichttpbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 999999999;
            XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
            quotas.MaxArrayLength = 999999999;
            quotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 999999999;
            quotas.MaxDepth = 999999999;
            quotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 999999999;
            quotas.MaxStringContentLength = 999999999;
            basichttpbinding.ReaderQuotas = quotas;




         EndpointAddress address=new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:52855/WCFService1/Service.svc");

         ChannelFactory<IService> objClient = new ChannelFactory<IService>(basichttpbinding,address);



         IService obj =   objClient.CreateChannel(address);
         obj.GetData(1);

        }
```

Please help me..
Thanks..

Edit: Please don't say "use a config file" etc. I'm doing this only because I have no other choice and have to do it this way.Thanks

**Edit: More detailed info after tracing...**

```
  </PRE>This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service. For example:</DIV></BODY></HTML></MessageLogTraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262164</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:42.6268846Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{927d4271-a71b-43e6-a8c8-b5b69f5a1b4d}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="6" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageSent.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Sent a message over a channel.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext+HostedRequestHttpOutput/65311427</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTraceRecord"><MessageProperties><Encoder>application/xml; charset=utf-8</Encoder><AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching></MessageProperties><MessageHeaders></MessageHeaders></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Stop">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:42.6278847Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{927d4271-a71b-43e6-a8c8-b5b69f5a1b4d}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="6" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Stop"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Process action ''.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ProcessAction</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262168</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.2142614Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{a38d441f-464e-4816-a084-8d6c8b484b59}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectToIPEndpoint.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Connection information.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager/5669220</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><LocalEndpoint>::1:52855</LocalEndpoint><RemoteEndpoint>::1:0</RemoteEndpoint></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.2142614Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{a38d441f-464e-4816-a084-8d6c8b484b59}" RelatedActivityID="{91bc1c27-5688-4e02-956b-48a9a7e6872c}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Suspend">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.2142614Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{a38d441f-464e-4816-a084-8d6c8b484b59}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Suspend"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Listen at 'http://localhost:52855/WCFService1/Service.svc'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ListenAt</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Start">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.2142614Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{91bc1c27-5688-4e02-956b-48a9a7e6872c}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Start"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Processing message 2.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ProcessMessage</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.2142614Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{91bc1c27-5688-4e02-956b-48a9a7e6872c}" RelatedActivityID="{a38d441f-464e-4816-a084-8d6c8b484b59}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Stop">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.2142614Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{91bc1c27-5688-4e02-956b-48a9a7e6872c}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Stop"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Processing message 2.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ProcessMessage</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Resume">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.2142614Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{a38d441f-464e-4816-a084-8d6c8b484b59}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Resume"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Listen at 'http://localhost:52855/WCFService1/Service.svc'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ListenAt</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131075</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.2172616Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{a38d441f-464e-4816-a084-8d6c8b484b59}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Throwing an exception.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.CreateMessage()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details. ---&amp;gt; System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.CreateMessage()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.</ExceptionString></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262164</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.2912658Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{a38d441f-464e-4816-a084-8d6c8b484b59}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageSent.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Sent a message over a channel.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext+HostedRequestHttpOutput/2389992</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTraceRecord"><MessageProperties><AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching></MessageProperties><MessageHeaders></MessageHeaders></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131076</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-14T07:42:49.3462690Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{a38d441f-464e-4816-a084-8d6c8b484b59}" /><Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="4596" ThreadID="9" /><Channel/><Computer>UNIQUETOP</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Handling an exception.</Description><AppDomain>46847491-1-129498325594327019</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.CreateMessage()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details. ---&amp;gt; System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.CreateMessage()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ExceptionUtility.TraceHandledException(Exception exception, TraceEventType eventType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Comment: You should probably enable debug logging/tracing and post more detailed information on your problem if you cannot then solve it.

Comment: @avid, I've posted the trace now after enabling logging and tracing..

Comment: you'll probably have more luck if you just post the error from the trace instead of that huge mess.

Comment: @Nathan do you mean using the svctraceviewer tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted, it looks like your client is expecting to interact with an IIS-hosted service, given the .svc extension in the URI:

```
EndpointAddress address=new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:52855/WCFService1/Service.svc");
```

You didn't state whether your service is IIS-hosted or self-hosted, but you did say a config file is not an option.  I see two ways to resolve the issue you encountered:

**IIS-Hosted**

1. In order to programatically configure the ServiceHost under IIS, you will need to either:

   a. Implement your own classes deriving from ServiceHost and ServiceHostFactory.

   b. Put the code in-line in the .svc file.
2. If you choose to implement your own derived ServiceHost and ServiceHostFactory classes, you'll need to specify your ServiceHostFactory-derived class in the @ServiceHost tag in the .svc file.

**Self-Hosted**

1. In your server code, specify an URI for each endpoint in the AddServiceEndpoint method call.
2. In your client code, pass the same URI to ChannelFactory when creating the channel.
3. In this case, you will not have a .svc file.
4. Don't forget to close the proxy on the client when you're done - especially if you're using IIS.

I hope this helps get you pointed in the right direction.  If you need more information, just ask.

Comment: Tim, I compared the webconfig settings that get automatically generated while referencing my wcf server and found that I needed to include more settings on the client.